# spark streaming job suddenly exits on FileNotFoundException

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming, amazon-emr

I am running a Spark streaming application where each batches writes its final output to S3 in parquet format by using SqlContext.

I am able to get this application to run successfully in EMR.

However, after running for a couple of hours, the spark jobs suddenly halts on a `FileNotFoundException`.

I am not sure what to do next here.

Any pointers in how to debug/fix this issue would be useful.

I use Spark 2.2.1, EMR 5.1.1 and Java 8 for my application.

My streaming application code

```
 public class StreamingApp {
    JavaStreamingContext initDAG() {
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        // new context
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, batchInterval);
        SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

        ...

        // Converting to Dataset's Row type
        JavaDStream<Row> rowStream = inputStream.map(new ObjectToRowMapperFunction());

          // Writing to Disk
        rowStream.foreachRDD(new RddToParquetFunction(sqlContext));
        return jssc;
    }
    ...
}

public class RddToParquetFunction implements VoidFunction<JavaRDD<Row>> {

  private final StructType userStructType;
  private final SQLContext sqlContext;

  public RddToParquetFunction(SQLContext sqlContext) {
    userStructType = ProtobufSparkStructMapper.schemaFor(UserMessage.class);
    this.sqlContext = sqlContext;
  }

  @Override
  public void call(JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD) throws Exception {
    Dataset<Row> userDataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, userStructType);

    userDataFrame.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet("s3://XXXXXXX/XXXXX/");

  }
}
```

appropriate spark driver logs

```
18/02/15 22:47:57 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(comm  ands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:508)
    at app.functions.RddToParquetFunction.call(RddToParquetFunction.java:37)
    at app.functions.RddToParquetFunction.call(RddToParquetFunction.java:17)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStreamLike$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1.apply(JavaDStreamLike.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:256)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File s3://XXXXXXX/XXXXX/output/_temporary/0/task_20180215224653_0267_m_000032 does not exist.
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.listStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:996)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.listStatus(S3NativeFileSystem.java:937)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.listStatus(EmrFileSystem.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:362)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:47)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:207)
    ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you pay the premium for Amazon's [consistent EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-consistent-view.html) you can't reliably use S3 as a destination for your work.

ASF Hadoop+ Spark has fixed this on Hadoop 3.1+ with the [S3A committers](https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases). Without that, and on amazon EMR, you need to write to HDFS and then use distcp to copy up the results if needed. If chaining together work, leave on HDFS.